# Set up Skype business on local network

Tags: skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper, skype4com, skype-bots

Can we use the skype business solution on the local network only? 
The purpose is that the complete set up will be placed on local network and users within a local network be able to make calls and share the desktop screens. 
I was exploring the skype web-control and interview API but wasn't able to find any information about setting up everything locally. 
In addition to this, I also need the recording of the call saved on a local server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Skype for Business can be installed and restricted to the local network. The installation docs will cover the basic steps, and you can leave out steps related to exposing SfB externally (e.g. external certificate, DNS records). For the call recording, there are a number of commercial vendors providing solutions, or depending on the requirement you could build a custom solution